# ctypes function call fails on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I have this code that calls a libc function:

```
import sys
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')

class CpuSet(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('bits', ctypes.c_ulonglong * 16)]

print(ctypes.sizeof(CpuSet))
cpu_set = CpuSet()
tid = int(sys.argv[1])
rc = libc.sched_getaffinity(int(tid), ctypes.sizeof(CpuSet), ctypes.addressof(cpu_set))
print(rc)
```

When I run this with Python 2, I get a success rc "0", and when run it with Python 3 the printed rc is -1. The errno value is set to EFAULT, which according to [the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_getaffinity), means "A supplied memory address is invalid". However, `ctypes.addressof(cpu_set)` seems to return a valid pointer. I printed the sizeof value, just to be safe, and it's 128 on both pythons.

```
# python3 /tmp/test.py 2740
128
-1
# python2 /tmp/test.py 2740
128
0
# python2 -V
Python 2.6.6
# python3 -V
Python 3.8.1
```

I run the code under root on both cases.

Any idea why this happens, or what further tests I can perform?

**UPDATE**: I ran both pythons with strace, and there is a difference:

```
# strace python2 /tmp/test.py 17526 2>&1 | grep sched_getaffinity
sched_getaffinity(17526, 128, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]) = 8
# strace python3 /tmp/test.py 17526 2>&1 | grep sched_getaffinity
sched_getaffinity(17526, 128, 0x1da22030) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

It looks like python 3 passes the wrong pointer? Or maybe the struct doesn't get initialized? Still not sure.

Comment: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I printed the return value from `ctypes.addressof` and noticed that in python 3, the pointer got truncated:

```
# strace -e raw=sched_getaffinity python3 /tmp/test.py 2740 2>&1 | grep 'getaffini\|addressof'
write(1, "128\naddressof cpuset: 0x7fabee87"..., 37128
addressof cpuset: 0x7fabee8710b0
sched_getaffinity(0xab4, 0x80, 0xee8710b0) = -1 (errno 14)
```

This wasn't happening in python 2, probably because the pointer fit in 32 bits:

```
# strace -e raw=sched_getaffinity python2 /tmp/test.py 2740 2>&1 | grep 'getaffini\|addressof'
write(1, "128\naddressof cpuset: 0x193aae0\n", 32128
addressof cpuset: 0x193aae0
sched_getaffinity(0xab4, 0x80, 0x193aae0) = 0x8
```

Looking at the docs again, I saw that the recommended way to pass a pointer was using [`byref`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref) and not `addressof`. I changed the code to use `byref`, and it worked:

```
# strace -e raw=sched_getaffinity python3 /tmp/test.py 2740 2>&1 | grep 'getaffini\|addressof'
write(1, "128\naddressof cpuset: 0x7fb5d46f"..., 37128
addressof cpuset: 0x7fb5d46fb0b0
sched_getaffinity(0xab4, 0x80, 0x7fb5d46fb0b0) = 0x8
```

Not sure why the value returned from addressof got truncated. Perhaps casting it to a pointer type would also have worked?

Comment: ctypes assumes integers are passed as 32-bit and pointers are passed according to architecture size.  `addressof` returns an integer address and is truncated when passed on the stack if architecture is 64-bit and the parameter isn't declared as a pointer.  Set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for your functions to avoid problems and allow `ctypes` to perform better error checking.